# What is Some in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, match, ocaml, algebraic-data-types, option-type

This Ocaml code traverses a list and outputs the last element.

I dont understand the second condition where we output `Some x`

```
let rec last = function 
| [] -> None 
| x::[] -> Some x
| _ :: t -> last t ;;
```

- So if the list is empty we return null.
- If x is the last element we return `Some x` (* what is Some x in this context? *)
- If x is not the last element we go further in the list.

Comment: If the list is empty, we don’t return “null” (that doesn’t exist in OCaml), we return `None`. `None` and `Some x` (where `x` is any value of some type `t`) are the possible values of the option datatype over type `t` (i.e. `t option`). This is covered for example in [this beginner’s tutorial](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/a_first_hour_with_ocaml.html#Our-own-data-types) (see section “Our own data types” and the following one, “Dealing with errors”). See also [that other tutorial](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/null_pointers_asserts_and_warnings.html).

Comment: In this code, function `last` returns an optional value because it can fail: when the input list is empty, there is no value to be returned. So `last []` returns `None` and `last [0 ; 1 ; 2]` returns `Some 2`. Any code that uses the value returned by `last` must check whether it is `None` or `Some`, by pattern-matching on this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Some` is a constructor for the `option` type. `None` is the other constructor. Consider the following definition of `option`.

```
type 'a option = None | Some of 'a
```

The net effect of this is to provide for functions to have an *option* to return a value, or a value representing nothing. Imagine I want to search for the index of an item in a list. What should I return if the value isn't in the list?

```
let find_index value lst = 
  let rec aux value lst idx =
    match lst with
    | [] -> None
    | x::_ when x = value -> Some idx 
    | _::xs -> aux value xs (idx + 1)
  in
  aux value lst 0
```

```
utop # find_index 4 [1; 8; 2; 5; 4; 10];;
- : int option = Some 4
─( 17:10:49 )─< command 3 >──────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # find_index 4 [1; 8; 2; 5; 7; 10];;
- : int option = None
```

Both values have type `int option` so OCaml's type system is happy.

In your example, an empty list doesn't have a `last` element, so you return `None`.

We can then pattern match on this to handle the two situations:

```
let some_list = [2; 3; 4]

let () =
  match last some_list with
  | None -> print_endline "This list doesn't have a last item."
  | Some item -> print_endline ("The last item found was " ^ string_of_int item)
```

You may have run into languages where this type of situations is handled by returning a special error value. We could return `-1` for instance. Or we could throw a `ValueNotFound` exception.